# UDP Socket: recvfrom() returns -1 (SOCKET_ERROR)

Tags: c#, c++, sockets, recvfrom

I'm working on a server-client application based on UDP protocols. The server is written in c++ and the client is in C#.

On the server side I get the buffer using the recvfrom():

```
int bufLen = recvfrom(s, buf, 1024, NULL, (sockaddr*)&addr, &addrlen);
```

The weird thing is that the received buf is exactly what I've sent from the client but the bufLen is -1 which is SOCKET_ERROR.

I have no idea what the problem might be. please help. Thanks a million.

Comment: What is errno or the result returned from GetLastError()?

Comment: It printed out 10040. what does that mean?

Comment: I'm guessing WSAEMSGSIZE.

Comment: I'm confused. what does it mean and how I'm supposed to solve it?

Comment: Look, just Google 'Windows error 10040'.  Then look at the client code to see what size datagram you sent.

Comment: OK, got it. the datagram is small right?

Comment: No - the datagram is too big.  Bigger than 1024.

Comment: It's larger than your buffer, so it gets trucated, you get an error return from recvfrom and GetLastError() returns 10040, ('WSAEMSGSIZE').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your datagram is too big, or your buffer is too small.

The datagram is larger than your buffer, so it gets trucated, you get an error return from recvfrom and GetLastError() returns 10040, ('WSAEMSGSIZE').

Comment: My buffer size is the exact length of the buffer sent from the client. how can I use a bigger datagram?

Comment: Hmm.. are you sure?  Check again, and double the buffer to 2048 to see what happens.

Comment: I doubled the buffer to 2048 as you said and saw the received buffer length was larger than what I expected. I think I have to look for the problem somewhere else. thanks anyway.